# How to start and stop an application in a cluster of 21 computers?

Tags: windows, networking, automation, remote-control, application-launch

I have a network of 21 computers with identical software.

I want to start the software on all 21 computers (from a 22th computer).

I want to stop the software on all 21 computers (from a 22th computer).

All computers run Windows 10 Pro (1903)

This is for testing reasons. Currently I push the new version of the application with robocopy to all machines and the start them all by hand (and stop them all by hand).

I already thought about programming my own service, that runs on each computer but that's a lot of extra hours, and I don't think that I'm the first one doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same as you are doing `robocopy` to 21 computers, probably with a batch
script, you could execute the software on these computers in the same way.

The tool to use is
[psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec):

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information about remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer from [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for everyone having the same issue:

### There are a few preconditions to make the [PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) (psexec, pskill, etc.) from [Sysinternals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) work on Windows 10:

- The user that's used in the PsTool's parameters has to have a password given

  - Set a user password [CTRL] + [ALT] + [DELETE]
  - To avoid password prompt on logon launch `netplwiz` and uncheck "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer"
- Enable printer/file sharing for this computer
- [Stop UAC from preventing remote execution](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2013/04/24/resolve-access-is-denied-using-psexec-with-a-local-admin-account/) or you will get `Access Denied` when sending commands to your remote machine

  - > 1. Open RegEdit on your remote machine
    > 2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
    > 3. Add a new DWORD value called LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
    > 4. Set its value to 1